# How to communicate exceptions between routes in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a Camel Application which makes a call to a RESTFul service.

I expose a RESTful and a SOAP interface to my clients

Both the RESTful and the SOAP routes end up calling a common route which actually makes the call to the RESTFul service.

So, it s little like

```
<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="RESTFUL_INTERFACE" />
    <camel:to uri="direct:CALLEXTERNAL_REST_SERVICE" />
    <camel:to uri="ADAPT_RESPONSE" />
</camel:route>

<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="SOAP_INTERFACE" />
    <camel:to uri="direct:CALLEXTERNAL_REST_SERVICE" />
    <camel:to uri="ADAPT_RESPONSE" />
</camel:route>

<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="direct:CALLEXTERNAL_REST_SERVICE" />
    <camel:to uri="EXTERNAL_RESTFUL_SERVICE" />
</camel:route>
```

If my call to EXTERNAL_REST_SERVICE fails ( Connection refused for example ), then I need to take different actions in my REST and SOAP routes. As far as I can tell, `onException` applies only to the route it is specifed in.

How do I communicate the failure in `direct:CALLEXTERNAL_REST_SERVICE` back to the "outer" routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an onException for your camel context (this will be applied to all routes within). From there, onException is simply just another route. You can have a CBR, for example, and specify what to do next, based on where the exception occurred.

Comment: I'm quite new to Camel - What's a CBR?

Comment: Content Based Router: <choice><when></when></choice> http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html

Comment: Ok - thanks - but how would that Route know what it's origin was? How would it know that if it was replying to a REST request it should return an HTTP 500 code with some JSON, while if if was from a SOAP request it should return HTTP 200 with a SOAP FAULT message?

Comment: ok - looks like I can use exchange.getFromEndpoint() to do that. Thanks